# What is difference between insert 'event' or not?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function whichButton() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = event.keyCode;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onkeyup="whichButton()">

<p><b>Note:</b> Make sure the right frame has focus when trying this example!</p>

<p>Click on this page, and press a key on your keyboard.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Above is code of w3schools.com that I modified.

Original code had parameter 'event' like this : whichButton(event)

I wonder what is function of that parameter 'event' and why people insert that 'event' parameter.

I deleted that 'event' parameter from above code, but it still works fine.

I think that code is not wrong. There must be something that I don't know...

Comment: In some browsers, `event` refers to a global variable (a property of the `window` object). In others, the event object is passed as a parameter to event handlers and is not a global variable. Try your code in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The "event" is a facultative event callback parameter, it can be used to get lot of informations like which key was fired.

See [Event](http://www.google.com/translate?hl=en&ie=UTF8&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Ffr%2Fdocs%2FDOM%2Fevent) for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit `event` is not valid in all browsers and should not be used. My guess is that `event` was added to some browsers for compatibility reasons.

The following test tells us if they are references to the same object:

```
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) { alert(e === event); });
```

Internet Explorer 11: `true`

Google Chrome 39: `true`

Mozilla Firefox 33: `ReferenceError: event is not defined`

Comment: is this the same on all browsers?

Comment: I thought it was, but no it's not. They are equal in Chrome and IE. In Firefox however, I get `ReferenceError: event is not defined`.